# purrr::pmap with anonymous function versus lapply

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

Jennifer Bryan's presentation [(https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows-in-r-with-the-tidyverse)](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows-in-r-with-the-tidyverse) convinced me that my resolution for this semester will be to fully commit to the tidyverse approach. However, already my first coding session ended with a failure:

```
# load the necessary packages
library(tidyverse)

# create examples of my data set
prob = tibble(names = letters[1:17])
sample1 = sample(letters, 5)

# tidyverse approach, does not work
pmap(sample1, function(x) prob == x)

# basic R approach, does work
lapply(sample1, function(x) prob == x)

# how can I change the pmap code to make it work?
```

All the online anonymous function pmap examples did not include a different object ("prob" in my case), so maybe that is the problem? Or more likely I am missing something in how to specify the anonymous function?

Comment: instead of  `pmap`, use `map`

Answer (score 3):

Use `map()` instead of `pmap()` (as phiver suggests)

- `map()` works with one argument
- `map2()` works with two arguments
- `pmap()` works with a list of argument

Answer (score 0):

Or use: `pmap(as.list(sample1), function(x, ...) prob == x)`

Edit:

Thanks Karl, I was wrong actually, it should rather be `pmap(list(sample1), function(x) prob == x)` as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I always thought that a vector was a list, but apparently there are differences between list and vector (e.g., in the pmap case). Just changing the code to `pmap(list(sample1), function(x) prob == x)` worked already, without the `...`. `pmap(as.list(sample1), function(x) prob == x)` does not work, and `pmap(as.list(sample1), function(x, ...) prob == x)` does not calculate what I needed, the same as `lapply(sample1, function(x) prob == x)`.